# Difference between DriverManagerDataSource and SimpleDriverDataSource

Tags: spring, jdbc, datasource, spring-jdbc

In Spring, what is the difference between using **DriverManagerDataSource** and **SimpleDriverDataSource** for creating a new datasource given its driverClassName, url, username and password?

For example with DriverManagerDataSource you can do something like:

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

While with SimpleDriverDataSource you can do:

```
SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
Class<? extends Driver> driver = (Class<? extends Driver>) Class.forName(driverClassName);
dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the described point of view there is little difference. The main difference is conceptual and comes into play in OSGi environemnts - citing the [DriverManagerDataSource javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html):

> Within special class loading environments
>   such as OSGi, this class is effectively superseded by
>   SimpleDriverDataSource due to general class loading issues with the
>   JDBC DriverManager that be resolved through direct Driver usage (which
>   is exactly what SimpleDriverDataSource does).

Answer (score 3):

**DriverManagerDataSource** — Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface, configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties, and returning a new Connection from every getConnection call.

**SimpleDriverDataSource** — Similar to DriverManagerDataSource except that it provides direct Driver usage which helps in resolving general class loading issues with the JDBC DriverManager within special class loading environments such as OSGi.

[More Info](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/11/configuring-datasource-in-spring-framework.html)